# Patent Claim Drafting

Tags: patent-infringement, patent-applications, patent-lifetime, patent-services, patent-infringment

why in US a preemptive claim is patent ineligible and why the absence of complete preemption also does not demonstrate that a claim is eligible.

Comment: You are presumably talking about claims that preempt all uses of a law of nature. A law of nature is not patentable. A claim that preempted all possible uses of a law of nature is essentially an attempt to patent that law of nature.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Your comment makes a reasonable answer.

Comment: This is well beyond my expertise, but I found the following articles that may provide insight: https://www.finnegan.com/en/insights/revisiting-the-role-of-preemption-in-patent-eligibility.html and https://www.ipeg.com/patentable-subject-matter-and-preemption/

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'll read it and discuss

Answer (score 1):

You are presumably talking about claims that preempt all uses of a law of nature. A law of nature is not patentable. A claim that preempted all possible uses of a law of nature is essentially an attempt to patent that law of nature.